# Seleccionar cierta cantidad de Inputs a partir de un option

Tags: javascript, html

busque en el foro pero no encontré solución, lo que busco es que a partir de un option que tiene definidos los numeros 1, 3 y 5, se puedan seleccionar las mismas cantidades en una lista con inputs esto para enviar un formulario por correo, agradezco la ayuda

```
<li>
<label>No. de Seminarios de tu interes <span class="required">*</span></label>
  <select name="seminarios" name="seminarios" id="seminarios" >
    <option>1</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>5</option>
  </select>
</li>
```

```
<li> Selecciona los seminarios
<p><input type="checkbox" value="seminario1">Seminario 1</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" value="seminario2">Seminario 2</p>                            
<p><input type="checkbox" value="seminario3">Seminario 3</p>                            
<p><input type="checkbox" value="seminario4">Seminario 4</p>                            
<p><input type="checkbox" value="seminario5">Seminario 5</p> 
</li>
```

y como tal al unico codigo que llegue fue este pero creo no es el correcto

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$(‘#cantidad’).change(function(){
var valor= $(“#cantidad”).val();
if (valor==4){ $(‘#seminarios’).selectmenu( “1” ); 
}else{ 
$(‘#seminarios’).selectmenu( “3” ); }
})
})
```

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Realicé unas modificaciones tanto a tu código `JS` como a tu `HTML`, agregué un `value` a tus `options` y cambié el de tus `checkbox`, esto con el fin de poder comparar dicho valor con cada una de las opciones:

```js
$('#seminarios').change(function(){
  var valor= $('#seminarios').val();
  
  //console.log(valor);
  
   $('input:checkbox').each(function(e){
    if($(this).val() == valor){
        $(this).attr("checked", "checked");
    }
});
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
<label>No. de Seminarios de tu interes <span class="required">*</span></label>
  <select name="seminarios" id="seminarios" >
    <option disabled selected>--Seleccione--</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
  </select>
</li>

<li> Selecciona los seminarios
<p><input type="checkbox" value="1">Seminario 1</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" value="2">Seminario 2</p>               
<p><input type="checkbox" value="3">Seminario 3</p>              
<p><input type="checkbox" value="4">Seminario 4</p> 
<p><input type="checkbox" value="5">Seminario 5</p> 
</li>
```

Lo que hice fue obtener el valor del `option`, recorrer por medio del `each` cada uno de los `checkbox` y marcar aquella opción que coincida con dicho valor obtenido del `option`. Te dejo la documentación de la función `each`: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Te comento que tienes errores de sintaxis en tu `JQuery`, ya que las comillas que utilizas no son las indicadas.

Espero te ayude. Saludos.